# How does this python nested for loops work?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Can anyone explain why the output of the following nested loop is `{1:6, 2:6, 3:6}`?

```
>>> {x:y for x in [1, 2, 3] for y in [4, 5, 6]}
{1:6, 2:6, 3:6}
```

Comment: what result did you expect?

Comment: Post the code here. Highlight the text, and press ctrl-k to indent.

Comment: see the result of: [[x,y] for x in [1,2,3] for y in [4,5,6]] and of {1:2, 1:3}

Comment: How many items do you want in the dictionary, 3 or 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_dict = {x:y for x in [1,2,3] for y in [4,5,6]}
```

is the same is creating it as follows

```
my_dict = {}
for x in [1,2,3]:
    for y in [4,5,6]:
        my_dict[x] = y
```

Which would look like this if you unroll the loops:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[1] = 4
my_dict[1] = 5
my_dict[1] = 6
my_dict[2] = 4
my_dict[2] = 5
my_dict[2] = 6
my_dict[3] = 4
my_dict[3] = 5
my_dict[3] = 6
```

You are effectively inserting nine key value pairs into the dictionary. However, each time you insert a pair with a key that already exists it overwrites the previous value. Thus you only ended up with the last insert for each key where the value was six.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is you are making a dictionary vs a list. In your own example, you are effectively constructing a dictionary and because you set a different value for the same key 3 times, the last value sticks.

You are effectively doing:

```
dict[1] = 4
dict[1] = 5
dict[1] = 6
...
dict[3] = 4
dict[3] = 5
dict[3] = 6
```

So the last value sticks.

Answer (score 0):

If the expectation was to create `{1:4, 2:5, 3:6}`, try this:

```
{x[0]:x[1] for x in zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])}
```